# How to fix R "ERROR: no information for variable 'CXX11', 'CXX11STD' and 'CXX11FLAGS'"

Tags: c++, r

When I try to do `install.packages("seqminer")`, I get the following error:

```
configure: CC = gcc -std=gnu99
configure: CFLAGS = -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g
configure: CXX = ERROR: no information for variable 'CXX1X' ERROR: no information for variable 'CXX1XSTD'
configure: CXXFLAGS = ERROR: no information for variable 'CXX1XFLAGS'
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/Rtmp2qP3iH/R.INSTALL6ffb49156e3b/seqminer':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘seqminer’
```

I tried every possible solution I can find online excluding downgrading my gpp because I need to use this version. So far I edited my `/etc/R/Makeconf` like this:

```
CC = gcc -std=gnu99
CFLAGS = -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g $(LTO)
CPICFLAGS = -fpic
CPPFLAGS = 
CXX = c++
CXXCPP = $(CXX) -E
CXXFLAGS = -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g $(LTO)
CXXPICFLAGS = -fpic
CXX11 = g++
CXX11FLAGS = -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g
CXX11PICFLAGS = -fpic
CXX11STD = -std=gnu++0x
```

In summary, I changed all `CXX1X` occurences to `CXX11` and all `c++11` occurences to `gnu++0x`. I tried to change it to `gnu++11`, `c++0x` and `c++11` too. None of them works. The error I have now is almost the same:

```
configure: CC = gcc -std=gnu99
configure: CFLAGS = -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g
configure: CXX = ERROR: no information for variable 'CXX11' ERROR: no information for variable 'CXX11STD'
configure: CXXFLAGS = ERROR: no information for variable 'CXX11FLAGS'
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/Rtmp2qP3iH/R.INSTALL6ffb49156e3b/seqminer':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘seqminer’
```

My versions:
I use Ubuntu 16.04 in this machine.
My R version is: 3.2.3.
gcc/g++/c++ version is: (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609

I can't find the `config.log`.

When I try to do `R CMD config $VAR` with these settings for VARS `CXX11 CXX11FLAGS CXX11FLAGS CXX11PICFLAGS and CXX11STD` I get the following error:
`ERROR: no information for variable 'CXX11STD'` etc.

I don't have any local `Makeconf` to override. e.g. `~/.R/Makeconf` does not exists.

I tried setting env variables and getting them to check if they exist:

```
Sys.setenv("CXX11STD"="-std=g++11")
Sys.getenv("CXX11STD")
```

Works as it should be. But then I try to install package again, it still gives me same error.

Comment: Can you run g++ and c++ from the command line?

Comment: Yes. Running `g++ --version` gives me this output: `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

Comment: And running `c++ --version` gives me this output: `c++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609 Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

Comment: `CC = gcc -std=gnu99` is incorrect. `-std=gnu99` must be in `CFLAGS`.

Comment: There's no problem about the CC part. It was originally like this. And I still have the same error when I change it as you said.

Comment: Can you paste the outputs of `R CMD config --all`?

Comment: Maybe you can install the GitHub version of seqminer: `devtools::install_github("zhanxw/seqminer")` ?

Comment: When I do `R CMD config --all`, I get `ERROR: no information for variable '--all'`

Answer (score 0):

Clone its repo and update its configure file as follows.

```sh
git clone https://github.com/zhanxw/seqminer.git /tmp/seqminer
cd /tmp/seqminer
vim configure
```

Comment out these lines in the configure file as those variables are not set correctly.

```sh
CC=`"${R_HOME}/bin/R" CMD config CC`
CFLAGS=`"${R_HOME}/bin/R" CMD config CFLAGS`
CXX11=`"${R_HOME}/bin/R" CMD config CXX11`
CXX11STD=`"${R_HOME}/bin/R" CMD config CXX11STD`
CXX11FLAGS=`"${R_HOME}/bin/R" CMD config CXX11FLAGS`
CXX="${CXX11} ${CXX11STD}"
```

Install the package from the local source in an R session.

```
install.packages("/tmp/seqminer", repos=NULL, type="source")
```